# Swift/Python Reference Counting Difference

Tags: python, swift, memory-management

What is the difference between Swift's Automatic Reference Counting and Python's (manual) reference counting?

Is it because Swift supports `weak var` to automatically clean up circular data structures, while in Python there is no such thing and you have to manually `del` it, otherwise memory leaks?

Comment: CPython will automatically detect and clean up reference cycles. https://pythoninternal.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/the-garbage-collector/

Comment: Python doesn't have "manual" reference counting, reference counting is the garbage collections strategy used in CPython's *automatic memory management*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift ARC(Automatic reference counting), According Apple

> Swift uses Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) to track and manage your app’s memory usage.
>   ARC automatically frees up the memory used by class instances when those instances are no longer needed.

Swift will delete object while reference count equal 0.

Python use Garbage collector

Comment: @Hatshepsut Could you tell me what I wrong, please.

Comment: @ThanhVu I think in C you need to manually `delete` everything. In Python, only on circulars. In Swift, never (hence, automatic RC). CMIIW.

Comment: @Ron Maybe I'm wrong, When I saw this `The default Python implementation, CPython, is actually written in the C programming language.` I think it same,

Comment: Python's memory management is automatic; the garbage collector will clean up circular references automatically.

Comment: CPython is written in C, but it has many features that C doesn't have. Likewise Swift is written in C++ but is a very different language from C++. Python even has  additional implementations like PyPy, which is written in Python itself.

Comment: @Hatshepsut where does Automatic RC make difference, then?

Comment: @Ron I dont know swift, so I cant say what the difference is.

Comment: @Ron After read https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/. I think swift ARC and python ref counting is same. Addition, Python add Garbage collector to resolve reference cycles problem.